# How to integrate restrictions for user like Screen time/ Parental control in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, settings, restriction

How to integrate screen time/ Parental control API in iOS app. Is screen time api available?
I tried with MDM(Mobile device management) but I am unable to create the MDM CSR. As there is no option for this certificate on developer account.
Please guide me if you have any solution. Basically I want to create an app having restrictions like screen time in iPhone or parental control app.

Comment: You need to apply to Apple for the MDM certificate, but Apple is limiting the use of MDM capabilities for parental controls (See [clause 5.5](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#mobile-device-management)).  There is no api for screen time. It can only be configured through settings

Answer (score 0):

You can use apple ScreenTime api (Managed Settings, Family Controls, Device Activity) to block and shields iOS application on iOS Devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be done through settings. I use parental control app - FindMyKids to track my kids' location and what they are doing during the day. I have an iPhone as well and no problems.